# Is npm init needed?

Tags: node.js, npm

I always thought that you should initialize npm first before installing any packages

```
npm init --yes
```

However I found out that I could just go straight to installing packages

```
npm i example-package
```

Then the package would be installed and package.json would be created at the same time.

Is there any reason I should be doing npm init first? Is it only required if I want to specify project details?

Comment: what if you need write pure js lib (without any deps), how you init your project? :)

Comment: @YegorZaremba then you would just use npm init to specifiy project details if you release the project to npm

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not required. You can install packages without, and everything will work.

`npm init` can do basically two things:

- ask for basic project info to include in packages.json
- create a specific type of project (for example React) by using `npm init typeofproject`

If you just want to use packages and don’t care about naming the project or using a template, just install packages.

Comment: What Sami said, Also note that you can always run `npm init` after installing packages. It doesn't have to be at the start of the project.

Answer (score -1):

`npm init` is there when you are installing the project very first time.

else you don't need to use `npm init` for installing any package

Comment: The author was asking if you can install packages in a new project right away without running `npm init`, not if you need to run it before every package install.

Comment: Read the very first line and last line author asked. My answer completely meant for the asked question.

Comment: but I saw that I could run npm install without npm init in the first place

Answer (score -1):

Well, kind of a late answer, but as far as I know (correct me if im wrong), one of the features is it gets set up with `package.json` which includes the dependencies list. That way, NPM can simply install the packages on the list (via the "npm init" if you have a situation that you want to clone the app into another machine), rather than copy pasting the whole project folder.

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but, if sheds some light at some point, why not.

Comment: The packages.json still gets created without using npm init first.