# Installed npm packages without npm init

Tags: npm, dependencies, node-modules, package.json, init

I forgot to initialize npm by "npm init" and then installed other npm packages like express,ejs etc. inside my current project directory.
Where are these packages stored since no package.json file is created?
How do i find them?
Do i need to uninstall them?

Answer (score -1):

Npm version 8.7.0 will automaticly create the package.json and package-lock.json files and the node_modules folder in the directory where you ran `npm install` from.

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/57229830/18691323, `npm init` only adds basic project infomation to the package.json file, or creates a certain type of program.

You can check your version of npm with `npm -v`.